# What is the time to calculate the CRC

Tags: network-programming

If the message length is 2 bits or 1500 bytes, does it make difference in terms of time to calculate the cyclic Redundancy check (CRC)?

in other words, how much time does it take to calculate the CRC for 2 bits and for 1500 bytes?

Comment: This question is difficult to answer because this will depend on your hardware. Processing more data will take longer for sure but absolute numbers are difficult to share.

Comment: Many thanks for your comments. Now, is it possible to run the CRC on only 2-bit?. I have an idea that will allow me to calculate only 2-bit. For example, if the packet is 1518 bytes, then I need to calculate the CRC for the first 2-bit in each hop while the rest only one time (at the source and the destination at but in the cloud), so is it acceptable to calculate the CRC for only 2-bit ? to make sure that the data in these 2-bit reach correct in each hop.

Comment: What exactly would be the point? Why do you think you need a CRC over two bits, and not over the remaining thousands?

Comment: I have invented a new protocol, which enables me not to check the information in the packet while going from the source to the destination. Thus, the protocol should calculate the CRC at the source and then only at the destination, but not in the middle, even if there are 100 hops.

Comment: I have invented a new protocol, which enables me not to check the information in the packet while going from the source to the destination. Thus, the protocol should calculate the CRC at the source and then only at the destination, but not in the middle, even if there are 100 hops. This is regarding the packet. Regarding the new headers in the packet which is only 2 bits, they will be calculated at each hop from the source to the destination. Therefore, the protocol will save time by only calculate the CRC for only 2 bits in the middle hops instead of the whole packet/frame. Best Regards.

Answer (score 2):

The calculation time is *O(N)* in the length of the message.

There is no such thing as a 2-bit message. Did you mean two *bytes?*

If you're serious, the time to calculate the CRC of two bits can be *O(1)*, as it only needs a four-element lookup table which you can precompute.